# Google App Engine join results of two tables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, join, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a blog project using jinja2 for templates, Google App Engine for hosting and running it and Python as the server side language.

So, my `models.py` looks like this :

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    fullname = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=True,required=True)
    photo = ndb.StringProperty()
    location = ndb.StringProperty()


class Post(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = ndb.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
```

Now what I want is to have a result set like this :

**`User.fullname | User.Photo | Post.*`**

I am showing the above details for a single post. Now each ***`Post`*** entry is linked with a ***`User`*** with the User's Key.

Now since joins are not supported in ndb query class, how do I fetch and merge the two results ?

I tried the GQL like this :

```
select User.fullname, User.photo, User.id, Post.title, Post.content, Post.created
from User, Post
where User.__key__ == Post.user
```

But I get this error when I run this in the GQLQuery in my datastore console :

> GQL query error: Encountered "," at line 2, column 10. Was expecting
>   one of: "group", "limit", "offset", "order", "where"

---

Any suggestions ?

TIA

---

**EDIT:1**  Tried this query :

`posts = ndb.query(User,Post).filter(User.key == Post.user).order(-Post.created)`

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

---

**EDIT:2** Here is an index I tried :

```
 kind: Post
  properties:
  - name: content
  - name: created
  - name: user
    direction: desc
```

But doesn't seem to work :O

Comment: joins are not supported. the query you show has an implicit join. you need to join manually not with a query.

Comment: @ZigMandel: Yep right! That is why I tried this : `posts = ndb.query(User,Post).filter(User.key == Post.user).order(-Post.created)` but unfortunately I get this error : `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: that would again be a join and joins are not supported. goto first comment.

Comment: But this isn't an explicit join. Anyways, what do you suggest @ZigMandel ?

Comment: explicit or not is a minor syntax detail. Joins are not supported and this is a typical issue on any nosql database. you must do the join with code and the appropriate indexes must exist.

Comment: @ZigMandel: Can you suggest the necessary index for such a query ?

Comment: do show us first what index and query you have tried. the ones you are showing are not part of the documentation as they attempt to invent a join syntax.

Comment: `- kind: Post
  properties:
  - name: content
  - name: created
  - name: user
    direction: desc
`
I have tried this. But how do I write the query @ZigMandel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113833/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-zig-mandel).

Comment: it will not be a single query. Google a little for example "joins in appengine datastore" 3rd result shows one way to simulate joins but with possibly many queries.

Comment: Okay yes wait! Let me try one query as shown in the link

Comment: Hey @ZigMandel : I tried this, but no luck : http://pastebin.com/7ksTPprs

Comment: read s.o. guidelines for [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). include code **in the question** and show exactly what fails and how.

Comment: If this type of query is something you need to do a lot, you should consider denormalizing the data or keep another model that is an aggregate of the required properties that you need in the result set, so you don't have to attempt a join in code.

Comment: @TimHoffman : I did it by using 2 for loops. 1) one will iterate over the user objects 2) will iterate over post objects and then inside this for I do something like `Post.user_key == User.key` to match the Posts with the Users! I am not sure whether this is the best way though!

Comment: Yes, a couple of loops (or a set of async queries and set operations) are about it for joins. If you use this a lot (say most requests) you may find it far more efficient to create intermediate entities that hold all of the properties you use frequently and save a large number of queries/fetches

Comment: @TimHoffman : By any chance do you know how does one add new models to the the appengine's datastore ? I am going to start a new thread too -- But just decided to ask you first here!

Comment: The same way you created them in the first place.  Define the model and create an entity.  Now if your trying to create an intermediate entity, you would do this in stages. 1. Add the model, 2 run code (a task) to create the new entities, then 3. Add code that uses these new entities.

Comment: @TimHoffman : I did not know that Datastore was so dynamic that I wouldn't see the tables until I had data in it! Anyways thanks for your help Tim!

Comment: First thing to remember - there are no tables as far as the Datastore is concerned ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an array of dictionaries like this :

```
class HomeHandler(BlogHandler):
    def get(self,user=None):
        posts = Post.query().order(-Post.created)
        all_users = User.query()
        likes = Likes.query()

        list_dict = []

        for p in posts:
            p_dict = {}
            for u in all_users:
                if p.user == u.key:
                    p_dict['p_id'] = p.key.id()
                    p_dict['p_title'] = p.title
                    p_dict['p_content'] = p.content
                    p_dict['p_created'] = p.created
                    p_dict['a_name'] = u.fullname
                    p_dict['a_id'] = u.key.id()
            for l in likes:
                if l.post == p.key:
                    p_dict['like_count'] = l.like_count
                    list_dict.append(p_dict)

        if user_email:
            self.render('home.html',user=loggedin_user,
                                    list_dict = list_dict)
        else:
            self.render('home.html',user=loggedin_user,
                                    list_dict = list_dict)
```

And then in the template I iterate over the list like this and get data from each dictionary item :

```
{% if list_dict %}
      {% for l in list_dict %}
           //get stuff like this 
           // l['p_id'],etc
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I found this better way better as iterating over lists and dictionaries is very easy and time consuming.

Comment: Whoever down voted, please help me with constructive feedback! :)